# My dplyr::filter function keeps displaying different errors

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I am doing analysis on a VCF file, after using the vcfR::maf function, I got myself a data frame that contains four columns: A, B, C, D, each with number as value, no NA.

[I output the data frame to a csv and this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAqRx.png)

I named this data frame AF and is now trying to filter rows according to column D according to value, leaving only the ones with number in Column D >= 0.1, and name the new data frame as AF_MAF

I used this code

`AF2_MAF <- AF2 %>% filter (Frequency>=0.1)`

After encountering different errors I searched for solution and did

`library(magrittr)`

`library(dplyr)`

Now I get a new error:

Error in UseMethod("filter") :
no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')"

I searched and did not find corresponding solutions. Help please, Thank you soooo much!

Comment: `AF2` seems to be a matrix. Try `AF2_MAF <- AF2 %>% as.data.frame() %>% filter (Frequency>=0.1)`

Comment: ! It worked!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message it seems `AF2` is a matrix, you can change it to dataframe and then your code should work.

```
AF2_MAF <- AF2 %>% as.data.frame() %>% filter (Frequency>=0.1)
```

Alternatively, you can also subset the matrix.

```
AF2_MAF <- AF2[AF2[, "Frequency"] >= 0.1, ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm new to R and did not realize the formatting issue so I simply assumed the output was a data frame without realizing there's another format called matrix. Thanks for pointing out the problem!

Comment: Oh! Thank you for the reminder, just realized this function ;D

Answer (score 1):

Using `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(AF2, AF2[, "Frequency"] >= 0.1)
```